# Unir arrays e intercalar em php

Tags: php

Tenho esses 2 arrays:

```
$musica = [
    ["file" => "musica1"],
    ["file" => "musica2"],
    ["file" => "musica3"],
    ["file" => "musica4"],
];
$aviso = [
    ["file" => "aviso1"],
    ["file" => "aviso2"],
];
```

Estou tentando fazer um loop onde a cada 1 musica ele adiciona 1 aviso...

```
$resultado = array();
foreach ($musica as $mIndex => $mValue) {
    $resultado[] = $mValue;
        foreach ($aviso as $aValue) {
        if ($mIndex % 1 == 0) {
            $resultado[] = $aValue;
        }
    }
}
echo json_encode($resultado);
```

Dessa forma ele retorna o seguinte resultado:

```
musica1
aviso1
aviso2
musica2
aviso1
aviso2
musica3
aviso1
aviso2
musica4
aviso1
aviso2
```

Gostaria que fosse assim:

```
musica1
aviso1
musica2
aviso2
musica3
aviso1
musica4
aviso2
```

Comment: `if ($mIndex % 1 == 0)`, existe algum número que não é divisível por 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para intercalar os elementos do array `$aviso` com os elementos array `$musica`, desde que:

- Ambas a listas não sejam vazias.
- O comprimento de `$musica` seja maior que comprimento de `$aviso`.

Itere pelos elementos do array `$musica`, adicione ao resultado o item atual de `$musica` e em seguida adicione ao resultado um elemento do array `$aviso` cujo o índice é o resto da divisão do índice do item atual em `$musica` pela [quantidade de elementos](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.count) no array `$aviso`.

```
$musica = [
    ["file" => "musica1"],
    ["file" => "musica2"],
    ["file" => "musica3"],
    ["file" => "musica4"],
];
$aviso = [
    ["file" => "aviso1"],
    ["file" => "aviso2"],
];

$resultado = array();
foreach ($musica as $mIndex => $mValue) {
    $resultado[] = $mValue;
    $resultado[] = $aviso[$mIndex % count($aviso)];
}
echo json_encode($resultado, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

Resultado:

```
[
    {
        "file": "musica1"
    },
    {
        "file": "aviso1"
    },
    {
        "file": "musica2"
    },
    {
        "file": "aviso2"
    },
    {
        "file": "musica3"
    },
    {
        "file": "aviso1"
    },
    {
        "file": "musica4"
    },
    {
        "file": "aviso2"
    }
]
```

<sup>Teste o código no [IdeOne](https://ideone.com/CQDvoG)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

Segue uma solução.

```
$resultado = [];
$umDois = 1;
foreach ($musica as $mIndex => $mValue) {
    $resultado[] = $mValue;
    $resultado[] = 'aviso' . $umDois; 
    
    $umDois = $umDois == 1 ? 2 : 1; 
}
echo json_encode($resultado);
```